# Posting file to server with dropzone

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload, dropzone.js

I am using dropzone in my php application but i am unable to post the file to the server, i am rather new to dropzone have read the documentation but still having issues like this.

This is the html code:

```
<div id='dropzone'>

</div>
```

This is the javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/dropzone.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#dropzone").dropzone({ 
            url: "profile.php", 
            maxFilesize: 8, 
            paramName: "Displaypic", 
            addRemoveLinks: true 
        });
    });
</script>
```

I would like to understand how i can get the file into the file array and access such file from the server side.

Answer (score 0):

Dropzone is just the image handler for creating the stack. The actual upload is not handled by dropzone, but through php or javascript. I chose php. I never liked the way they did it on their tutorial and had several issues, so I came up with my own way. This is my uploads.php file.

```
<?php 
session_start();
//The $_SESSION['x'] variable is serialized using 
//     date("Y_m_d") . "-" . date("h_i_sa")
//This allows the file names to appear like this at the end...
//                              2015_07_07-12_35_22pm1.jpg
//                              2015_07_07-12_35_22pm2.jpg
$newname = $_SESSION['x']; 
$ds = "/";  //1
//My upload folder for the images.
$storeFolder = "/photos";  
$ext = "jpg"; // My Format is .jpg so I chose to restrict to jpg only!
$_SESSION['count'] +=1;
//count is added to the end of the file name so that each name is unique.
$name = $newname.$_SESSION['count'] .'.'.$ext;

if (!empty($_FILES)) {
  $tempFile = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];                       

  $targetPath = dirname( __FILE__ ) . $ds. $storeFolder . $ds;  

  $targetFile =  $targetPath. $name;  

  //Change IP address for host
  $host = "10.10.10.10";
  $port = "21";
  $timeout = "300";
  $ftp = ftp_connect($host,$port,$timeout);
  // Change user and password
  $user = "user";
  $pass = "password";
  ftp_login($ftp,$user,$pass);

 $ret = ftp_nb_put($ftp, $targetFile, $tempFile, FTP_BINARY, FTP_AUTORESUME);

 while (FTP_MOREDATA == $ret)
   {
    // display progress bar, or someting
    $ret = ftp_nb_continue($ftp);
   }
}  ?>
```

Comment: Not sure why you got downvoted; thought it was a pretty good server-side implementation. Personally I'd have opted for just moving the files into a folder rather than a remote FTP connection but you probably are remotely hosting the images or something. Upvoted anyway!